# Why is my user permission SQL code resulting in a user schema being created?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm granting permissions to a Windows authenticated user (only the default 'public' server role was previously present, with no user mappings or securables added), in the example below in the master db, but it is also creating a user schema:

```sql
--Database Context
USE [master]

--Role Memberships
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename=[db_datareader],@membername=[Username]
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename=[db_datawriter],@membername=[Username]

--Database Level Permissions
GRANT CONNECT TO [Username]

--Set default schema
ALTER USER [Username] WITH default_schema = dbo
```

Whilst the permissions are correctly set, I'm unclear why it is also creating a user schema. I've checked online and I can't see anything that would explain it.

Is this a result of sp_addrolemember, due to the user not existing in the database?

Comment: Could you tell more about how the user is created?

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified that this is to map permissions for a Windows authenticated login which has been created at the server level (updated original question to reflect). Only the default 'public' server role was previously present, with no user mappings or securables added.